# Git push production ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push to production and am getting this error:

Checkout using philc user key #

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '#' to the list of known hosts.

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists. git command i returned 128:
```

Philc is an engineer's account who's no longer here. It looks like it's using his keys, how can I switch it to my keys? I should've been able to push since my Github account is an admin on the repository. What could be the issue? Looked around at other similar questions, but I'm new to this and need steps for the commands I should input in terminal to fix this.

I want to try switching to a different Github account to push to production and see if that works. What are the Terminal commands to switch to another account, push to production, and switch back to my account?

Comment: Are you also using Phil's computer (whose Git was likely configured locally for him)?

Comment: No, I'm using my own computer and pushing through my Github account, in which I'm an admin of the repo. After I push to production, I check the status on CircleCi, and my build fails due to this error.

Comment: Did you check that your URL is correct? Username is specified in URL.